# ReferenceError: io is not defined - when socket server is different than localhost

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets, socket.io

A lot of questions with same title but this one is different which I could not find in existing stack overflow collection.

I have a socket server at different host and I want to use this socket server for my web app.

I tried to use this inside my index.html file of my angular application this way:
**index.html**

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="onecss.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ui-view></div>
<script ng-href="{{socketURL}}"></script> <!-- $rootScope.socketURL = "https://example.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"; -->
<script src="bower_components/angular-socket-io/socket.js"></script>
<script src="commSocket.js"></script>
<script src="onejs.js"></script>
</body>
```

**commSocket.js**

```
(function(app) {
    'use strict';
    app.factory('commSocket', function (socketFactory) {
        var socketUrl = "https://example.com";
        var ioSocket = io.connect(socketUrl); // Here io throws error. ReferenceError: io is not defined
        var options = {
            ioSocket: ioSocket
        };
        var socket = socketFactory(options);
        socket.forward('broadcast');
        return socket;
    });
})(app);
```

I think by the time https://example.com/socket.io/socket.io.js loads, commSocket gets called before and so it throws error. So my question is how can I wait for socket.io.js file to load completely before commSocket gets called.

This works fine if I connect to local socket.

Comment: why you need to use `ng-href` instead of just `src` or `href`?

Comment: Just updated, basically I am getting this value from a rootScope variable.